# Ensure that root user is running the client program that is trying to connect the server program

Tags: networking, network-programming

I have a server program which listens on a particular port.
I have a requirement where  client program that tries to connect to my server must be initiated by a root user.
How do I ensure this in the server program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client should bind to a port below 1024 before connecting. This port range is reserved for root.

Comment: but is not a denial of service for the port, which  client binds. Say the client wants to initiate a service for which my client prog has already binded.

Comment: Yes, the port will be blocked for others. This is however the traditional way of ensuring something is root.

Comment: You can always bind, connect to server from <1024, then also connect from >1024 and tell the server over the root connection that the other connection is OK.

Comment: That entirely depends on your setup. You could use kerberos if that applies to the environment, you could use username/password, you could use key-based authentication. But the "standard" way is to use this portrange

Answer (score 1):

> How do I ensure [*anything about the
>   client program*] in the server program?

You can't. If your security model requires the *server* to know whether *client* is root, you don't have security.

Let's consider one possibility: your network protocol includes a notification like this:

```
My-Uid-Is: 0
```

Your client, the perfectly secure version that you wrote, might implement this notification like this:

```
fprintf(socketFd, "My-Uid-Is: %d\n", getuid()); // send server my identity
```

But, my client, the one what I wrote without your knowledge or consent, will implement the notification like this:

```
fprintf(socketFd, "My-Uid-Is: 0\n"); // lie to server about my identity
```

Pop quiz: how can your server know whether it is talking to your truthful client, or my lying client? Answer: it can't.  In fact, if you generalize this concept, you realize that the server can't rely upon the validity (whether that means the truthfulness, the format, the range-checking, etc.) of *anything* the client says.

In this specific case, using the clients source port number is as unreliable as any other choice. Yes, many operating systems require root privileges to bind to low-numbered source ports. But my PC might not be running your favorite operating system. I might be connecting from my own PC running my own OS which doesn't have that feature. Remember: you can't trust anything the client says.

There are techniques involving public-key encryption that can be used to guarantee that the program you are talking to has access to specific secrets. That, assuming that the secrets are adequately protected, can be used to guarantee that a specific person, computer, or account generated the request. I'll let someone else discuss PKI and how it might apply to your situation.

Comment: Very nicely said... thanks... but the solution given by Erik provides sufficient enough security as of now... will think of the public-key encryption as TODO